# swift iOS resize view on scroll

Tags: ios, swift

I have a VC with a navigation bar and then a uiview under it that acts as an extension to the navbar.

Then I have a embedded table view.

What I would like to do is to add a scroll recogniser to the container view that holds the table view so when I scroll down the uiview under the navigation bar should be hidden.

Is this possible? I have used `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)`
In order to hide the navigation bar and that works. The problem is that I now need to hide the uiview under it. And I can't get it to work/feel smooth since just a hide/show functions looks strange. I would like it to be hidden the same speed as I scroll

Comment: Do you have a constraint that pins the top of the UIView to the top of the ViewController? If not, add that and create an IBOutlet for the NSLayoutConstraint. Then override the func scrollView viewDidScroll of the tableView and resize the constraint accordingly.

Comment: @Caleb thanks I will try that. Do I need layoutifneeded() or something else when changing the constraint?

Comment: I don't think so. I can run a test later if you can't get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 8 has advaced functionality for such effects already buildin. See here: 
http://natashatherobot.com/navigation-bar-interactions-ios8/

Comment: navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true doesn't feel that smooth since you have to do a swipe. I am looking for something like in the Facebook app, where the hiding is very synced to the force of the scroll

Comment: http://iosdevtips.co/post/84571595353/replicating-uiscrollviews-deceleration-with

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188416/add-a-floating-bar-to-a-scroll-view-like-in-the-facebook-ios-apps-timeline

Comment: Thank you for those posts @Darko